# How to install ghc 7.6.3 on Ubuntu 16.04.1?

Tags: ide, haskell

Okay, so I'm trying to learn how to code in haskell because it's delicious compared to C. My problem is that I've no idea how to set it up after downloading it from the official GHC site: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/download_ghc_7_6_3

I downloaded this version and extracted it, and then followed these steps in the terminal: https://www.haskell.org/downloads/linux, which are the following:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y software-properties-common
sudo add-apt-repository -y ppa:hvr/ghc
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install -y cabal-install-1.22 ghc-7.6.3
cat >> ~/.bashrc <<EOF
export PATH="\$HOME/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.6.3/bin:\$PATH"
EOF
export PATH=~/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.6.3/bin:$PATH
```

Terminal didn't recognize the command "cat"...reported the following:

```
bash: export: `/.cabal/bin:/opt/ghc/7.6.3/bin:': not a valid identifier
bash: warning: here-document at line 120 delimited by end-of-file (wanted `EOF')
Command 'cat' is available in '/bin/cat'
The command could not be located because '/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable.
cat: command not found
```

It also didn't couldn't install "software-properties-common", whatever that is. I then downloaded Stack, but I don't know what to do with it. The instructions say to put it into the PATH, but I don't know how.

Comment: For some reason, it's not finishing the code in the first block, which is [code]
<<EOF
export PATH="\$HOME/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.6.3/bin:\$PATH"
EOF
export PATH=~/.cabal/bin:/opt/cabal/1.22/bin:/opt/ghc/7.6.3/bin:$PATH
[/code]

Comment: How exactly did you copy the instructions from the website into your terminal? did you paste them via a word processor program that might have added unseen characters or odd line endings by any chance?

Comment: @steeldriver I didn't copy the code from the website, I wrote it out myself. The source code appears to have been added to my software center, but the program is not appearing when I search for it in the center still. I also don't know what 'stack is".

Comment: Sorry I don't really have any other ideas - btw, why are you trying to do all this manual installation instead of just installing the supported version of the `haskell-platform` metapackage direct from the universe repository?

Comment: This is my third day as a Linux user, so I would prefer the simpler method, but I don't know how to do it. Can you tell me how? At this point, I've installed so much manually, I don't know if I could do it through the software center anymore without undoing what I've already done. Is the universe repository the same thing as the software center? What do I do to install this platform onto my system? I'M SO CONFUSED AND OVERWHELMED!!!!

Comment: okay, so I installed the haskell platform through the terminal, but I still can't find it on my system or in the software center. What now?

Comment: I've never used it, but my expectation is that it is just a collection of command line programs and libraries. You can read about possible IDEs for Haskell here: wiki.haskell.org/IDEs

Comment: Now I get it, I thought GHC was a compiler itself. This isn't explained anywhere on the net. Problem: When I type ghc into the terminal, I get the following: [code]ghc: no input files
Usage: For basic information, try the `--help' option.
[/code] What does that mean, did I install it incorrectly? It works fine if I type in ghci though.

Comment: You need to write a Haskell source code file, and then pass it to `ghc` as an argument e.g. `ghc -o hello hello.hs`. See for example [Haskell in 5 steps](https://wiki.haskell.org/Haskell_in_5_steps)

Comment: Typing that results in the following response: [code]<no location info>: can't find file: hello.hs[/code] I shouldn't try installing an iDE over ghc if it's not working correctly, right? I'd like to try Leksah!

Comment: Did you create the `hello.hs` file in your current directory with suitable contents (e.g. `main = putStrLn "Hello, World!"`) as described in the link?

Comment: ghci will recognize that line of code, but then if I type in [code]ghc -o hello hello.hs[/code] I get the following[code]<interactive>:3:1: Not in scope: `ghc'

<interactive>:3:7: Not in scope: `o'

<interactive>:3:9: Not in scope: `hello'

<interactive>:3:15: Not in scope: `hello'

<interactive>:3:21: Not in scope: `hs'[/code]

Comment: Sorry - comments are not the place for debugging this kind of thing, the lack of formatting makes it impossible. Make sure you are typing the `ghc` command in the **bash shell** not in the Haskell interactive **interpreter shell** (`ghci`).

Comment: I don't even know what a bash shell is, is the default directory you enter the terminal at the bash shell? It didn't work there either.